# Myspace app fails to publish with "app does not have valid icons" even though it does

Tags: icons, myspace

I want to create an app on Myspace. The app creates successfully, but when I publish it the following error occurs:

> Failed to publish app: Your app does not have valid icons. Please add a small and large icons and then re-publish.

I have selected 16 and 64 pixel icons, but when I click on the save button the following link opens and the icons do not save...

http://developer.myspace.com/modules/common/static/html/errorpage.html

Comment: Please provide more detailed information. What file format are your icon images? What image software are you using to save them? I would try another file format, probably try PNG first, GIF second, JPG as last resort. Sometime free editing software adds bad meta data to images, that is why I ask about the format and software being used.

Comment: So the first step is to go back to 2006...  (I kid, let me clean up your question a bit to make amends).

Comment: [Small Icon](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/16/social-myspace-box-blue-icon.png)
[Large Icon](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/64/social-myspace-box-blue-icon.png)

Comment: Try contacting the myspace support team about this. It could be some sort of bug (see this thread also: http://developer.myspace.com/community/forums/p/9328/44775.aspx).

Comment: Their contact page is also unavailable..........